# Triggering workflow_dispatch event not working from a Python script

Tags: python, github-actions, github-api

I am trying to use `workflow_dispatch` event for triggering a GitHub Actions workflow from a python script:

```py
import requests

url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{REPO_OWNER}/{REPO_NAME}/actions/workflows/{workflow_name}/dispatches"
header = {"Accept" : "application/vnd.github.v3+json", "Authorization": f"token {TOKEN}" }
data = b'{"ref" : "main"}'

requests.post(url, data=data, header=header)
```

I am not getting any error however workflow is also not getting triggered.

Please suggest.

Comment: What do you get in response?

Comment: First thing I'm noticing is `"Authorization": f"token {TOKEN}"`. Should be `"Authorization": f"Bearer {TOKEN}"`. See [Create a workflow dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event).

Comment: I am getting either timeout or getting 404 in response.

Comment: Is your repo private? What kind of token is that `TOKEN`?

Comment: I created Personal access Token -> Classic, and provided almost full access to it. It's not a publically accessible repo. Its repo of a customer project, which cannot be public

Comment: Right. Have you updated that `token` to `Bearer`?

Comment: Please verify with GitHub CLI i.e. [`gh workflow run`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow_run) that your token is working fine.

Comment: Might also try https://ghapi.fast.ai if you need more api usage, it helps abstract away some manual difficulties